# Connect to existing tables in database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am quite new to python. I am using flask to develope microservices using python. In order to connect to database  , I am using Sqlalchemy . Is there any standard approach like creating models , and connecting them to existing tables in db? And like Spring boot services , do we have repository classes for querying or what is the standard procedure. Any code snippet appreciated.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/

Comment: I have seen it already . What I am asking is if this is the proper approach or can we use METADATA and access the table when and where required without creating model class.

Comment: Yes and yes....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to create models *at all* by using the database's Metadata.

I used the following approach:

create engine

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('urlpwportetc...')
```

load the metadata using the engine as the bind parameter

```
metadata = sqlalchemy.Metadata(bind=engine)
```

make a reference to the table

```
my_table = sqlalchemy.Table('exact_table_name', metadata, autoload = True)
```

you can then start constructing your db queries using (for example)

```
query = my_table.insert()
query.values({'column': value1, 'column2': value2})
```

this is then executed with

```
my_session = Session(engine)
my_session.execute(query)
my_session.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to access the same table in two or three different files , should I still write the same engine,metadata code again ?

Comment: Up to you. In some cases, I reload Metadata per-request, because this allows "you" to make database changes and reflect them immediately without restarting your Flask server. This is a bit slow, so I wouldn't recommend it in production. For best speed, reuse the same engine everywhere

Comment: Yes you should reuse the same engine as much as possible. If you want to reflect database changes immediately, you can re-create the engine and metadata per-request, but this is not necessary in most circumstances.

Comment: Since 2024 (`SQLAlchemy>=2.0.28`), for me, step 2 of this way has to be changed: 
`metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(); metadata.reflect(bind=engine)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way of connecting your Flask-SQLAlchemy app to your database

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "any key"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Say you want to connect to MySQL database on your local machine it can be done this way. This will work if your database does not have any password associated with it. If your database has a password then you can add that password after root or username you have for your database.

```py
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root@localhost/database_name'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
```

And make sure that your server is up and running. The app needs to be told  about the tables in your database before you access the data in them. It can be done this way

```py
class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "name_of_table"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key = True , nullable=False)
    name= db.Column(db.String)
```

Any more fields can be added, it is just a small example 
and for every table in the database this has to be done so I suggest all this to be in a separate file.